# Load default system font for UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uiwebview, xcode8, ios10

I've two views on my view one is a `UIWebview` and other is a `UITextView` and I want both of them to display system default font. But, I just loaded a plain `HTML` text on my `UIWebview` and loaded another plain text on textview with default system font. On `UIWebview` it looks like Times New Roman and on textview it looks like Helvetica. Does the default system font differs for `UIWebview`?

This is the `HTML` page source that I load and below is a textview that uses system font.

```
<html>
<body>

This is a sample html Page


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIWebView` is just a Safari component inside your app. So when you put HTML content into it, you're kind of loading a page.

The default fontface for web content is Times New Roman, so if you want to change it you need to style your HTML content to change default fontface, using the same type as the system.

Comment: **Yogesh Mv**'s answer below this reply could help you out.

Comment: but what if the webpage is dynamic coming from any server, and want to show the system font if any font is not specified, if any font style specified, then should take that only

Answer (score 2):

I presume if you didn't specify the Font name in html it will take default Font from OS. The default font may vary based on OS and browsers. In iOS you can specify the default name like given below:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type=\"text/css\">
        body{font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue'; font-size:17;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

This is a sample html Page


</body>
    </html>
```

In the above code it will take apple default font. If it is not available it will take HelveticaNeue font.